# 'buf_size' extension

Tags: formatting, numbering

I have used LaTex for a number of years, but here is a new difficulty I have not found before (I quote from the output):

TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [buf_size=3000].

I only got 7 pages in the dvi file of a document that might have extended to 15 pages.  The added strangeness is that I have had no difficulty with producing 15 pages on a dvi document before.

How does one alter the 'buf_size'?  What accounts for the change in the matter?

Comment: The document is not too long.  There are people who have made books with hundreds of pages.  You probably have a syntax error on page 8 that is causing an infinite loop of some kind.  Try commenting stuff out until the problem goes away, then carefully add things back one at a time.  You should be able to find the problem in five to ten minutes this way.  If not, post some code here and someone will likely be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

`buf_size` is essentially the maximum size *of a single input line*  although it is also used for some macro expansion, so it is the line after tex macros expanded.

So either (most likely) your input document has no newlines and is all on one line or you have a very big tex expansion loop, or an infinite expansion loop.

You can increase the value in `texmf.cnf` file, but that will not help if you have an infinite loop.